# NodeJS MongoDB Times Out Loading Route

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am having troubles after moving all of my Controllers Routes and Models into their own files. I seem to only get a timeout when loading anything from the database and none of my console.log()'s run anymore, The model works and it posts the testPost (in the controller) perfectly fine. I tried adding the testPost because console.log() or errors aren't showing in my console.

**Controller**

```
//jshint esversion: 6 
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const Post = require(`./../models/posts`);
//Initial Post to posts Model
const testPost = new Post ({
    postTitle: `Default Post`,
    postDate:  Date.now(),
    postBody: `If you're seeing this, It means your DB is connected and you're ready to go!`,
    postAuthor: `Admin`
});
const defaultPost = [testPost];


//View Single Post
exports.showOne = function(req, res){
    const requestedPostTitle = req.params.id;
    Post.findOne({postTitle: requestedPostTitle}, function(err, foundPost){
        if (!err && foundPost){
            const title = foundPost.postTitle;
            const date = foundPost.postDate;
            const content = foundPost.postBody;
            const author = foundPost.postAuthor;
            res.render(`./post/post`, {
                title: title,
                date: date,
                content:content,
                author:author
            });

        }
    });
};
```

**Model**

```
//jshint esversion: 6 
const mongoose = require(`mongoose`);

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({

     {SCHEMA DATA}
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model(`Post`, postSchema);
exports.databaseName = `postsDB`;
```

**index.js Routes**

```
app.get(`/posts`, postPages.showAll);
app.get(`/post/:id`, postPages.showOne);
app.get(`/post/compose`, postPages.compose);
app.post(`/post/compose`, postPages.create);
```

Comment: You currently only respond in the !err case, have you checked whether there's an error?

Comment: Yes nothing shows, It happens on ALL routes not just showOne

Comment: After chasing my own tail thinking I was launching the server too early I Found an error by adding it directly into mongoose.connect(); which revealed my port was being blocked by a mongod request that didn't quit properly. I'm on Linux so I killed it and it is now working again. Lesson learned, check for errors on db start.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I moved my database startup into it's own file called db.js as per this great article that was referenced to me by another SO user:
https://theholmesoffice.com/mongoose-connection-best-practice/

After moving the configurations into db.js I logged the errors as per the article:

```
// If the connection throws an error
mongoose.connection.on('error',function (err) {  
  console.log('Mongoose default connection error: ' + err);
});
```

I had not realised that I wouldn't get error logs on database startup without this.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to send a request only after the connection to the DB was established.